# Stop click on child calling method on parent - React/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a modal in React. When you click the background of the modal, the modal should close. The way I have it set up right now, if you click inside* the modal, it closes as well. Because the modal is inside the background>

```
handleClose(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    this.props.history.push('/business/dashboard') 
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Background onClick={e => this.handleClose(e)} name="BACKGROUND">
        <Container onClick={console.log("IT CLICKED")} to={'/business/dashboard'} name="CONTAINER">
             ....
```

When I click on Container, the onClick event for Background gets called. I don't want this to happen. This is a form that users will be clicking on all the time. I need the modal to only close when you click outside the modal on Background.

Comment: while you could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside, the simplest solution is to give your modal an onClick handler that just stops the event from propagating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will work if you use `stopPropagation` on the `Container` click event instead of the `Background`. Just make sure that you use the `onClick` prop in your `Container` component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClose = (e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    this.props.history.push("/business/dashboard");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Background onClick={this.handleClose} name="BACKGROUND">
        <Container
          onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}
          to={"/business/dashboard"}
          name="CONTAINER"
        />
      </Background>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: On rereading the question, [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51109936/1290386) is a simpler solution in this case.

The behavior you want to achieve is generally referred to as an "outside click" handler. There are a couple of decent libraries to handle this [0] and their source is pretty short and readable if you want to know how it works in detail. [1]

The general idea is to register a click event handler on the document in a HOC and check whether the `event.target` originates inside a React `ref` via `Element.contains` browser functionality. If is is, the handler will not be executed.

[0] https://github.com/tj/react-click-outside

[1] https://github.com/tj/react-click-outside/blob/master/index.js